# How can I import CSV from phone storage to SQLite?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have a method to import a CSV file from folder "assets" to an SQLite table.

The CSV contains lot of lines like this one: France;Paris

But I don´t want to take the CSV file from "assets" folder, I would like to modify that method to import a CSV file from the phone storage folder(/storage/emulated/0) but I don´t know what I have to change to achieve it. Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

This is the method that I want to modify:

```
public void importPlayersTable(Context context){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
        InputStream inStream = null;
        try {
            inStream = manager.open("playersTable.csv");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
        String line = "";
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] colums = line.split(";");

                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("QUE_QUE", colums[0].trim());
                cv.put("ANS_QUE", colums[1].trim());

                db.insert(MI_TABLA_PLAYERS, null, cv);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
    }
```

Comment: Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / ` ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument` to let the user pick the CSV data. You will get a `Uri` from this. Call `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. From there, you can use it as you are using your `InputStream` in your current code.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you a lot for your answer. I was looking for information about your instructions and it helped me to improve my knowledge. I appreciate it. Unfortunately I am too new programming so it was difficult for me to solve the problem following your explanation, but I am sure they can be very useful for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post my solution based on @SweetD3v answer, just in case it is useful for someone else.

```
public void importPlayersTable() throws FileNotFoundException {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String filepath = "/sdcard/playersTable.csv";

        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(filepath);

        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
        String line = "";
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] colums = line.split(",");

                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                //cv.put("ID_PLAYER", colums[0].trim());
                cv.put("QUE_QUE", colums[1].trim());
                cv.put("ANS_QUE", colums[2].trim());

                db.insert(MI_TABLA_PLAYERS, null, cv);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
    }
```

I also had to add a try-catch in the class that calls the method:

```
try {
                    d.importPlayersTable();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import .csv file with FileReader and then save it to SQLite.
check this method.

```
private void csvToSQLite(String filePath){
 FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(filePath);
 BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
 String line = "";
 String tableName ="TABLE_NAME";
 String columns = "_id, name, dt1, dt2, dt3";
 String str1 = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + columns + ") values(";
 String str2 = ");";

db.beginTransaction();
while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str1);
    String[] str = line.split(",");
    sb.append("'" + str[0] + "',");
    sb.append(str[1] + "',");
    sb.append(str[2] + "',");
    sb.append(str[3] + "'");
    sb.append(str[4] + "'");
    sb.append(str2);
    db.execSQL(sb.toString());
  }
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Very complete and very useful. It helped me to solve my problem and improve my knowledge. I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. :)